# Cannot access returned data from Angular request

Tags: angular

For some reason, I cannot access the response from a request in an Angular project. Even if I can print it on console, I can access `data.status` and `data.response`, but when I try `data.response.entries`, I have the following issue.

My component:

```
  transportantions: any[]; //this is on the start of my component together with the rest of my variables

  getTransportations() {
    let loader = this.loadingController.create({
      content: 'Getting data...'
    });
    loader.present();   
    this.wpApi.getTransportations()
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if ( data.status == 200 ) {
          this.transportantions = data.response.entries;
          loader.dismiss(); 
        } else {
          console.log('Something was wrong. Error status ' + data.status);
        }  
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        loader.dismiss(); 
        console.log('something was wrong: ' + err);
      });
  }
```

This is the output from `console.log(data)`

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "response": {
    "total_count": "242",
    "entries": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

And the error I get is:

`something was wrong: TypeError: Cannot set property 'transportantions' of undefined`

Comment: Check for `data.response`. What you are getting ? Are you getting correct output?

Answer (score 2):

```
getTransportations() {
    let loader = this.loadingController.create({
      content: 'Getting data...'
    });
    loader.present();   
    this.wpApi.getTransportations()
      .then( (data) => { // just change the function format
        console.log(data);
        if ( data.status == 200 ) {
          this.transportantions = data.response.entries;
          loader.dismiss(); 
        } else {
          console.log('Something was wrong. Error status ' + data.status);
        }  
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        loader.dismiss(); 
        console.log('something was wrong: ' + err);
      });
  }
```

just change the function format.

> change function() {} format to this () => {} format in order to get access to 'this.transportantions';

more about arrow function:
**https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/**

Comment: It worked. So many thanks. Will choose yours since it was the first one. Just need to wait 7 minutes for the time limitation.

Comment: @Tasos Even if I agree with the "your answer was first" logic, You should take a look at the documentation I linked to understand how arrow functions work, because it's important to understand why it works with it while it didn't with a simple js function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an [arrow function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) instead of an explicit `function`, allowing you to keep the current context in the scope of the `function`:

```
getTransportations() {
    let loader = this.loadingController.create({
      content: 'Getting data...'
    });
    loader.present();   
    this.wpApi.getTransportations()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if ( data.status == 200 ) {
          this.transportantions = data.response.entries;
          loader.dismiss(); 
        } else {
          console.log('Something was wrong. Error status ' + data.status);
        }  
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        loader.dismiss(); 
        console.log('something was wrong: ' + err);
      });
  }
```

In your example, `this` is undefined because you lost the context in the `function` scope.